How to get "root" user to appear on the GUI login page in CentOS 8?
I was wondering if there is a way to get the "root" user to appear on the CentOS 8 GUI login page, and if so, how to configure that?

I found this on Reddit:

https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/11ora54/how_do_i_add_an_existing_user_to_the_login_screen/

And I was able to get the "root" user to appear on the GUI login page.
The /var/lib/AccountsService/users/ directory had several files that were named the same as users, in addition to a file named root.
So I removed all the files except the one named root, and I edited the file named root to contain:
id='centos'
version-id='8'

[User]
Session=gnome
Icon=/root/.face
SystemAccount=false

(The SystemAccount=false seems to be critical!)
I then rebooted the machine and then the root user appeared on the GUI login page (along with the other users).
